# What is portlet application's root web application?

Tags: spring, liferay, applicationcontext

The root web application context XML file is associated with the portlet application. The
web application context XML file for a portlet contains portlet-specific beans, whereas
the root web application context XML file contains beans that are accessible to all
portlets in the portlet application. A bean defined in the root web application context
XML can be overridden by the portlet-specific application context XML file by defin-
ing a bean with the same bean ID.

It is written in Portles In Action.

It said that we can use the bean that defined in the portlet application's root web application context XML file.

Any examples?

I defined a test bean in Portlet A with Sping Framework.

The Code:
web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext:

```
<bean id="testA" class="org.format.liferay.study.TestA" />
```

I get testA in Portlet A:

```
TestA test = (TestA)PortletApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getPortletContext()).getBean("testA");
```

It is success.

When I create Portlet B

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

The applicationContext.xml is empty.

So I can't get testA in Portlet B.

I want to know how to config the root application context in liferay

Comment: Whay did you show web.xml twice? Are your two portlets in same web application? Reading your question they are not.

Comment: two portlet in two projects.  I understand wrong..  It means that one project with many portlets can share the bean that defined in web.xml